# How to pass customize environment variable (like password) in stack with nix?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nix

I'm using stack with nix. I need to pass the environment variable as DB password to connect to Postgres while runtime. Currently, I enabled nix in the YAML and customized my own `.nix` to put the password in `.nix`.

stack.yaml:

```
nix:
  enable: true
  pure: true
  shell-file: shell.nix
```

shell.nix:

```
{ghc}:
with (import <nixpkgs> {});

haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
  inherit ghc;
  name = "myenv";
  buildInputs = [ postgresql_10 ];
  PGPASSWORD = "pw";
}
```

But when I want to commit the code into GitHub/Gitlab and go to CI/CD pipeline, explicit the password in `.nix` seems not good. I'd like to know is there a good way to deal with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `builtins.getEnv` function in a Nix expression to the value of an environment variable from the external environment, so you could do something like this:

```
PGPASSWORD = builtins.getEnv "PGPASSWORD";
```

This is just one way to set its value.  You could also use `import` to import a Nix expression file that you never commit to git, or you could use `builtins.readFile` to read a file that you never commit to git.

Note that none of these import methods will prevent the password from getting added to your Nix store (`/nix/store`) when you build your project.  If other people have access to your machine, you must consider the security implications.